# Controlling brightness on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: brightness, xrandr, xbacklight

I'm not able to change my brightness with the keys nor do I have an option to change them. 
Also I have tried using xrandr and xbacklight commands.

Comment: is this a laptop, desktop or what?  not all hardware allows for the setting to be changed via controls from the machine in the same manner. I recall doing some testing on how different laptops (with external displays) earlier this year responded to the same commands with commands to increment/decrement/%change brightness, backlight etc and it was very clear differences between models/brands/chipsets, internal, external..  I might have given more if I knew what commands you tried, what machine you have etc.

Comment: don't do what I just did. I enabled a Gnome Tweak that purported to do this though maybe without keystrokes), but, alas, it broke my system - blank screen on bootup. nomodeset got me in, but that tweak, which broke my system, was already disabled.  this is the little devil. the url even misspells xrandr https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1374/brightness-control-xranr/  I had to clonezilla back from last week.  AMD Ryzen 5 default amdgpu,